# Apache 1.4 Axis two almost identical clients how?

Tags: osgi, apache-axis

I have need for making two Apache Axis 1.4 clients in same application server war. Endpoints are different servers, but wsld-definitions are almost the same. This means that when they're updated they're not done at the same time. So the other must be in older version for a while.

How can I achive that? Using OSGi?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the sole purpose of using OSGi within your application, then I feel it as an over-kill. It's true, that OSGi modularity layer allows you to control your classpath. But the effort is not worthwhile if you are not using it across the application.

How about loading the two `jar` file versions using a custom `URLClassLoader` within your application. You can put the `jar` files in separate directories and load the clients using the custom classloader.

Just a thought. I don't know the exact context.

Comment: Good idea. We're using maven so placing jar files to separate directories is not an option. I have to investigate some more.